# url is not loading after entering the chrome profile using java-selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using below code to launch the url. But not loading the url.

```
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
      ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions(); 
      option.
      addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\vkandukur.ctr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\"
      );
      
      option.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 6");
      
      option.addArguments("--incognito");
     
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);//in selenium4
      
        driver.get("https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/");
```

Getting exceptions:
Starting ChromeDriver 105.0.5195.52 (412c95e518836d8a7d97250d62b29c2ae6a26a85-refs/branch-heads/5195@{#853}) on port 53422
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 400. Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
System info: host: 'INL1TBH6G3', ip: '192.168.43.148', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [user-data-dir=C:\Users\vkan..., --profile-directory=Profile 6, --incognito], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [user-data-dir=C:\Users\vkan..., --profile-directory=Profile 6, --incognito], extensions: []}}}]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:70)
at com.ironMountain.util.browserConfiguration.ChromeBrowser.main(ChromeBrowser.java:104)

can any one help please

Comment: This points to default profile `addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\vkandukur.ctr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");`. But this points to another profile `option.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 6");`.

Comment: How to overcome this issue?

Comment: How to overcome this issue? Without using those 2 lines, it is not opening the chrome browser page. If I used any 1 then it is opening the chrome profiles page. As we need to work with chrome brower page by passing url, we are unable to achieve it. Dont know where it is going wrong

Comment: You simply can not saying chrome to use `user-data-dir` of user A and `profile-directory` of user B.